# Why my PHP don´t catch data from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, web

This is my code. I check post.php and this show NULL. Before using the IF in PHP, I got Void with **var_dump($_POST['name'])**; and receive blank emails, only with the text of $contenido

```js
    <?php

var_dump($_POST[]);

  if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND !empty($_POST['subject']) AND !empty($_POST['message'])){
    
  $destino="contacto@mail.com";
  $nombre=$_POST["name"];
  $correo=$_POST["email"];
  $asunto=$_POST["subject"];
  $mensaje=$_POST["message"];
  $headers = "From: mi@cuentadeemail.com" . "\r\n" .
  $contenido="Nombre: ".$nombre."\nCorreo: ".$correo."\nAsunto: ".$asunto."\nMensaje: ".$mensaje;
             
  mail($destino, $subject, $contenido, $headers);
  header("Location: index.html");

}

?>
```

```html
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="post.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Asunto" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
                </div>
              </form> 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: !empty includes isset for free

Answer (score 0):

try changing your form action

```
action="post.php"
```

to

```
action="/url/post.php"
```

or be sure you are posting in correct place !

Comment: It is in the same level, in the root of my web

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `required="required"` The `required` tag is fine by itself.

As what Met Byrdy said, make sure you're POSTing to the right location. If post.php is in the same directory as your main-contact-form, then the `action="post.php"` is fine, but if it's not you need `action="path/to/post.php"`.

Comment: Thanks. My **post.php** is in the same directory as my **index.html**.

Comment: Take out all the if conditions and leave the isset($_POST['name']) and see if it works